# Accessing Module inside a Thread Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Service which calls a method that runs inside thread. But the code inside thread has access to other module methods. The thread is getting struck when the module method is called.

Service:

```
  def place_order
    threads = []
    @responses = []
    order_params.each_with_index do |order, index|
      threads << Thread.new do
        @responses << Module1::Class1.place_order(order)
      end
   end
   threads.each &:join
  @responses
end
```

Module1::Class1's place_order method:

```
def place_order(options)
  order_params = { body: order_config(options).to_json }
  resp = make_request(:post, "/v3/order/", order_params).parsed_response
  Rails.logger.info "QWIK_CILVER::ORDERResponse:: #{resp.inspect}"
  ***The below code calls a method in different module which is not running******     
  Module2::SubModule1::Class1.parse(resp, self)
end
```

THe server is hanged and I am not even able to stop the server after that. Have to kill the process manually and start the server again. How can I call the Module2::SubModule1::Class1's method inside thread?

PS: If I call the same service from console, everything works as expected. But If i call from postman, the server hangs at the modeule method call point.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not running"? Are you using `ruby-on-rails` version 3, or 5? (Or maybe 6??) -- You've tagged the question with both.

Comment: @TomLord Version 3 has been removed. And I have clearly mentioned that the server is hanged. I could not even stop the server.

Comment: You said that "the method in the other module is not running". What does this mean? Are you saying that the method never gets called? Or that it gets stuck halfway, in some code you haven't shown us? Does the rails log message appear?

Comment: Does your code all work as expected if you remove the usage of Thread?

Comment: I hope the method is not being called only. If I remove the thread , the code works as expected or if I remove the module method inside the same class as thread runs, the code works as expected. So I concluded that the method inside a different module is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Tracked down the issue. Ran the application Production mode and the same code works fine. Its a simple class loading issue in development mode.